# USB port getting too hot

Tags: usb, motherboard

In my friend's PC i have noted that his USB port is getting very hot. I cant keep touching it. Why is this happening? Is there a fault in motherboard or USB Controller?

Comment: Look closely at the port. Is there any sign of physical damage to the connector?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like power pins are shorted in the port. Don't use it or you can damage connected devices.

If it's an onboard port you should replace your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to make sure you have the right divers installed if you're not using the operating system that the laptop came with.

Comment: Its not a laptop. Its a PC

Comment: Sorry about that.. My answer is the same however as the lack of a proper driver can cause overheating due to a lack of proper communication and control over the USB/any controller.